# Steps to be followed for performance analysis of Java EE/Oracle application

Tags: sql, oracle, jakarta-ee

We developed an application using Java EE and Oracle and we want to increase the performance of it from both the Java and database side.

Need proper approach or steps to do this.

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the data which you have in your database. We can manage until 5 million data with out any problem,more than that you may get performance problems.

If you have massive data in your databank then go for database partition.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_range 
(salesman_id  NUMBER(5), 
salesman_name VARCHAR2(30), 
sales_amount  NUMBER(10), 
sales_date    DATE)
PARTITION BY RANGE(sales_date) 
(
PARTITION sales_jan2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('02/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')),
PARTITION sales_feb2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('03/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')),
PARTITION sales_mar2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('04/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY')),
PARTITION sales_apr2000 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('05/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'))
);

SELECT  *  FROM table PARTITION (partitionname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while creating Database model just go through database Normal forms
```

Like: 
    3NF,4NF and BCNF.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).